# Making images visible in a div using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

In my asp.net mvc4 view I have some nested divs to show an image and under it a text like below:

```
<div id="Outer1" class="elementStatus">
    <div class="image">
        <img id="MyImg1" src="@Url.Content("~/images/InitialImage.gif")">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        Statuts Text
    </div>
</div>

<div id="Outer2" class="elementStatus">
    <div class="image">
        <img id="MyImg2" src="@Url.Content("~/images/InitialImage.gif")">
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        Statuts Text
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.elementStatus
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.image{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 2px;
    padding-top: 1px; 
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 35px;    
}
.text{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 1px;
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    width: 35%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Like above code, i have some others, let's say, more than 20.

As you can see, the outer div, called outer, is initially hidden so neither images nor text is shown as I want initially. Also initially, some default images are set, and these initial images are animated gifs.

Then a process is started, and those div are set to visible (no images are changed).

**First issue** is that the images and text by default is not being visible (it continues hidden). If i set by default in css to visible instead of hidden they make visible.

What I do for doing them visible is:

```
$('#Outer' + elemId).prop("visibility", "visible");
```

Note that the line above is within a for, i mean, elemId will be 1,2, and so on...

**Second issue:**
If I set to visible in css from the beginning, then default animated gifs images and text is displayed, no problem, but during the process is being executed, I want to change those images for other news (not animated and these new images are PNG images, not gif) so I perform the following:

```
$('#MyImg' + elemId).prop("src", '@Url.Content("~/images/NewImage.png")');
```

Note again that in line above, elemId will be 1,2, and so on...

My problem here is that images are changed but they are shown as a black cross and then, after a few seconds, when the process is being terminated they begin to be visible correctly. What's wrong here?

Comment: Second issue is: Now once outer div is visible, at a certain moment during the process i change the animated gifs for other new images (PNG) but the problem is that image is not being updated immediately, it is updated with new image after a few seconds... However, the text under the image (that is updated at the same time the image is updated) is updated immediately but image not. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the style property, there is no property called `visibility` for the element, it is the style property that has visibility property.

So do:

```
$('#Outer' + elemId).css("visibility", "visible");
```

Most possible the black cross that you mention about images is probably the image url incorrect and browser shows just the placeholder for the image not found. If you check your console you might be able to see if the image url are actually being loaded or not (i.e if it is not you will see a 404 error).

Comment: Great! it works. And for my second issue? Now once outer div is visible, at a certain moment during the process i change the animated gifs for other new images (PNG) but the problem is that image is not being updated immediately, it is updated with new image after a few seconds... The text under the image is updated immediately but image not. Why?

Comment: @Rodri it depends on the size of the image as well. It is too large them it may take some time to load. What do you mean by text under the image by the way? is it a separate element or a part of image itself.

Comment: The text under the image is that div below the image div, see my post, it is marked with text:"Status Text". The new images are png and are 24x24 pixels and 1.29KB size. Anyway, the default animated gifs set as default intialy and then make it visible, is 30x30 pixels and 2.13KB size and in this case it is shown immediately. Why new ones being smaller in size and dimensions are now displayed immediatelly? the only difference is that new ones are changed in run-time by  modifying src property. maybe png is slower to load than gifs?

Comment: @Rodri What you can possibly do is use your network console possibly chrome there you can actually view the load times, ideally browsers cache them if they are form the same source and should not take time for image this small.

Comment: Could be that the process on going has priority on the image loading? so images are not being updated until almost the end of the process. Also I am wondering if there is some way to do a refresh of that div where the new image has just been loaded. Is there a refresh method for div?

Comment: @Rodri what is the on going process, It should load them as you set the src.

Comment: I have some IPs,then using jquery I create deferred tasks,and then pings begin to be executed against IPs.Each deferred task does a ping(this is the ongoing task/process, 1 for each ping to an IP) to only an IP of the list.Once deferred task finishes,it could be passed(if ping is ok)or failed(if ping is not ok),so once result of the ping is known(passed or failed)the default animated gif is changed by the new one, passed.gif if ping passed, failed.gif if ping failed, also the text is changed at the same time by "Passed" or "Failed".Text is changed immediately but image not.this is the problem.

Comment: I forgot to say that those tasks are asynchronous, non-blocking, using $.ajax. Anyway as you have solved first issue for me and you has helped me a lot, I accept your answer despite second issue is not solved for now. See the times network below: http://snag.gy/q6yWR.jpg

Comment: @Rodri looking at your image, it looks like fail.gif took 45 sec to load, that i believe is too much. is that the image you are talking about?

Comment: yes it is, but its dimensions and size is the same as the default animated gif, it should not take so time to load  I think. How can I solve it?

Comment: @Rodri You would have to find out what could be causing it to take a long time, how ever if you want to display text only if it loaded, you can detect that something like this `$("img").on('load', function() {
   //show the txt here
   
   })
   .prop("src", "image url")
   .each(function() {
 
        if (this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');
   });`